# Bootstrap Tooltip with manual trigger and selector option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dynamic table, loaded with ajax. I want to show a tooltip when I hover the mouse over a *row*, but I want the tooltip to appear over a certain *cell* (with class `.name`) instead of above the entire row.

Also, using title function, I need to be able to get closest row id and return a custom template.

**Here is my code**:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Statistics</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td >1</td>
            <td class="name">Name #1</td>
            <td>United States of America</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td >2</td>
            <td class="name">Name #2</td>
            <td>United States of America</td>
            <td>50%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Initialization**:

```js
$('#myTable').tooltip({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    selector: 'td.name',
    trigger: 'manual',
    title: function() {
        // here will be custom template
        var id = $(this).parent().atrr('id');
        return id;
    }
});
```

**Attempt One : [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLs3G/)**

```js
$('#myTable')
    .on('mouseenter focusin', 'tbody > tr', function() {
        $(this).find('td.name').tooltip('show');
    })
    .on('mouseleave focusout', 'tbody > tr', function() {
        $(this).find('td.name').tooltip('hide');
    });
```

**Attempt Two : [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLs3G/1/)**

```js
var tip;
$('#myTable')
    .on('mouseenter focusin', 'tbody > tr', function() {
        tip = $(this).find('.offer-name');
        tip.tooltip(hereAllTooltipOptions);
        tip.tooltip('show');
    })
    .on('mouseleave focusout', 'tbody > tr', function() {
        tip.tooltip('hide');
    });
```

But I wonder greatly over the performance of such a solution. So, the question is how to do it and do it better?

Answer (score 37):

The problem here is that you can't use the `selector` option when `trigger` is set to `manual`.  The [selector is used for delegation when bootstrap is handling the trigger events](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/0268b41c4f93e8f85c44a9ee2c8177c076c61ede/js/tooltip.js#L60), but you've explicitly said that you'll be the one handling delegation, so it [ignores the `selector` setting](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/0268b41c4f93e8f85c44a9ee2c8177c076c61ede/js/tooltip.js#L70).

This means we gain *nothing* from pre-initializing with code like this:

```js
$('.parent').tooltip({
    selector: '.child',
    trigger: 'manual'
})
```

It just says I want to set tooltips on `.child` elements, but don't do anything about it, because I'll be handling it later.

Which is fine, that's that what we wanted to do anyway when we used `manual`.  We'll be the ones to dictate when the tooltip is shown or hidden.

Let's look at what a simple case of that would look like:

```js
$('#myTable').on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $(this).find('td.name').tooltip('show');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $(this).find('td.name').tooltip('hide');
    }
},'tbody > tr');
```

#### [Demo in js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/xpeLr/2/)

However, this won't work in this instance because we want to dynamically generate tooltips.  When we call `.tooltip('show')` on a particular element, bootstrap looks at that element to see if it has been initialized or has a title.  The above example works, because I've hard coded in a title, but how would we use this if we wanted to initialize this tooltip first?

Just Initialize on the fly, right before you show the tooltip, like this:

```js
$('#myTable').on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $(this).find('td.name')
            .tooltip({
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                title: function() {
                    return this.parentNode.id;
                }
            }).tooltip('show');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $(this).find('td.name').tooltip('hide');
    }
},'tbody > tr');
```

So you don't incur the initialization cost on every hover, you can wrap the initialization in an if statement to [check if it has already been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24982555/1366033) like this:

```js
var $cell = $(this).find('td.name');
if (!$cell.data("bs.tooltip")) {
    $cell.tooltip({ /* options */ });
}
$cell.tooltip('show');
```

### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/xpeLr/)

Comment: Thank you!! That is exactly what I needed :). Also, just found I can use `$cell.data('bs.tooltip')`for check if tooltip has been initialised.

Comment: Bootstrap documentation on 'selector' is quite vague. I completely overlooked the possibility that dynamic tooltips can simply be generated on the fly using tooltip() function and options itself. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this code, I was able to use it for popovers as well. Also as a heads up: I intend to use this code without attribution in my progress since it appears you are giving it freely.

Comment: @KyleMit Thanks for the thoughtful reply. To me, it's just a hassle to attribute and keep up with them all. I actually usually keep a link back to the question in my source code, but that is usually it. And I may not do that if I understand the code myself. I asked about this one time (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution). Anyway, I do believe that you legally retain copyright and can allow others to use without attribution if you wish. For now, I will assume you do not wish to do that, which is completely acceptable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KyleMit . Ha, I think I can see you must have found it interesting because the number went up from 95 to 96 :) . Yes, please feel free to delete. take care